# Hundreds of Errors When Including "D3DX11Effect.h"

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

Whenever I include `D3DX11Effect.h` in my project, I get hundreds of errors from multiple different `DirectX` header files that do not give me errors when I do not include `D3DX11Effect.h`. These are my includes:

```
#include <string>
#include <dwmapi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <TlHelp32.h>

#include <exception>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

#include <D3D11.h>
#include <d3dx11.h>
#include <DXErr.h>
#include <D3DX11async.h>
#include <D3DX11Effect.h>
#include <D3Dcompiler.h>
#include <D3D11Shader.h>
#include <FW1FontWrapper.h>

#include "../Drawing/ImGUI/imgui.h"
#include "../Drawing/DirectX.h"
#include "../Drawing/imgui_dx11.h"
#include "../Drawing/ShaderFX.h"
#include "../Drawing/Renderer.h"

#include "Global.h"
```

I'm using `Direct X 11` and`Windows SDK version 10.0.16299.0`. I've tried reinstalling `DirectX` with no luck. Here is an image of some of the errors I'm getting:

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Paste the first few errors as text not an image.

Comment: Look at that ``File`` column. Those errors are showing up in ``d3d11.h``. It's probably because of syntax error in your code

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** Read [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx).

The DirectX SDK is deprecated, and the Windows 8.0 SDK, Windows 8.1 SDK, and Windows 10 SDK headers are *newer* than the headers that shipped in the legacy DirectX SDK. You are getting a mix of old headers and hew headers, which is why you are getting those errors.

The first thing to consider is if you need to use the legacy DirectX SDK at all. Ideally you just don't use it. This means avoiding the `D3DX11` utility library which itself is also deprecated. You can find a number of open source replacements for that functionality listed in the article [Living without D3DX](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/08/20/living-without-d3dx/), including the latest version of [Effects for Dirct3D 11](https://github.com/Microsoft/FX11/wiki).

You *can* continue to use the legacy DirectX SDK mixed with modern versions of the Windows SDK, but you need to do it with some care as explained at the bottom of the MSDN page [Where is the DirectX SDK?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx):

- VC++ Directory include/lib paths must be in *reverse* traditional order so you get the newer headers where they conflict
- You need to explicitly include `d3d11.h` and `dxgi.h` *before* you include `d3dx11.h` or you end up with the wrong version--which is exactly what happened above; you are using getting an outdated version of `dxgi` and/or `d3dcommon`.
- For `dxerr.h`, build your own version as explained [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/04/24/wheres-dxerr-lib/) because (a) it doesn't ship in the Windows SDK, and (b) the version that ships in the legacy DirectX SDK is not fully compatible with modern versions of Visual C++.

> Note that the error buried in your image: `C2440 static_cast cannot convert from const char[6] to char *` in `renderer.h` has nothing to do with the issue above. This is due to the fact that modern C++11 rules on string literals disallow using them as non-const. You should fix the code, but you can also turn off [strictstrings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn449508.aspx) if you don't care about portability/conformance. In any case, take some time to read up on [const correctness](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness).

See [The Zombie DirectX SDK](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2015/03/23/the-zombie-directx-sdk/) for a complete dissection of what headers conflict, which ones are unique to the DirectX SDK, and which ones have any value for DirectX 11 games on modern versions of Windows.

You should review the various posts I've made in the past 8 years on [this subject](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/tag/dxsdk/) as well.